# Strange Behavior with Templates After Creating a User Account

Tags: python, html, django

So I have an index page that checks if a user is authenticated and redirects them to a `workouts.html` page if they are authenticated:

```
def index(request, auth_form=None, user_form=None):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        context = {'user': user}
        template = 'workouts.html'
        return render(request, template, context)
    else:
        auth_form = auth_form or AuthenticateForm()
        user_form = user_form or UserCreateForm()
        template = 'index.html'
        context = {'auth_form': auth_form, 'user_form': user_form}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

There are also login/authentication views, but all of that works just fine. Where I'm running into problems is that I wrote a very basic template page for `workouts.html` to test the authenticated user redirect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>These are your workouts, {{ user.username }}.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I logged in with a test account. Everything works fine. However, now when I try to add extra html, like a logout form:

```
<form action="/logout">
    <input type="submit" value="Log Out" />
</form>
```

NOTHING shows up other than the HTML I've already rendered. I've tried restarting the server to the same effect. I also tried adding something much simpler, like

```
<div>wtf</div>
```

Nothing shows except the initial message. And if I delete everything on the page, I still get the `"These are your workouts, test1"` message. Even if I log a user out by hand, I get the same initial message. Why is the template engine not registering my new changes when all other behavior (form authentication, the initial rendering, url routing, etc.) seems to be working fine?

Comment: which template are you putting your code into ? `workouts.html` or `index.html`?

Comment: `workouts.html`, because the index view should redirect the user there each time they visit the homepage.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a wild guess, you should close this:

```
     <input type="submit" value="Log Out"
```

It would look like this:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Log Out" />
```

Possible reason: until the input is close, the browser interprets everything as part of "inside the input tag" which it never renders because it never closed.

Anyway: ensure your HTML is valid.

Comment: Alas, I tried this to no avail. Even adding extremely simple html like `<span>hi</span>` does not register. Even if I log the users out by hand and try logging in with a new user, I get the initial page.

Comment: Update your question please

Comment: It's actually all already in there, except for the logging users out and back in thing. I'll add that.

Comment: Yeah but the broken HTML in the question is kind of confusing, just trying to help.